# How to print 0.1 to 0.100 with increment c#

Tags: c#

I want to print decimal numbers from 0.1 to 0.100
In a loop, how can you print with increment?

```
for(decimal i=0.1;i<=0.100;i++)
{
   console.writeline(i);
}
```

My decimal value getting change from 0.10 to 1.0.

want to print  0.1 , 0.2,  0.3... 0.10,0.11, 0.12...0.100

Comment: FYI, in math, `0.1` and `0.100` are the same number, so `0.1 == 0.100` is true (well, [floating point math is (famously) broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken))

Comment: I think the easiest way would be to iterate over `int`s and simply print a 'dummy' decimal number: [Example fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/9uc9ft)

Comment: 0.1 and 0.100 are the same number, so you actually don't want to output values from one to the other.

Comment: Given the results you desire, my impression is that you don't actually want numbers in the mathematical sense, but rather a special sequence for some other reason.

Answer (score 3):

Well the root problem is that `0.1` and `0.100` are the same number. Also that `i++` is [syntactic sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar), it is equal to `i = i + 1`. It seems like you don't want the numbers in the mathematical sense, but in the "version" sense (like version `1.1` is older than `1.10`), and in that sense each number (before or after the dot) is treated as a [natural number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number), i.e positive integers.

In your particular case, the positive integers between (and including) `1` and `100`, and then just print them out in a fancy format, which is easy enough:

```cs
for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"0.{i}");
}
```

P.S the `$` before the string signals to C# that this is a [interpolated string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated), they're really cool and useful.

Comment: The version-sense remark is interesting. It is possible to do `for (var i = new Version(0, 1); i <= new Version(0, 100); i = new Version(0, i.Minor + 1)) { Console.WriteLine(i); }`. Also note that if the asker really needs decimal, you can parse, as in `for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) { var dm = decimal.Parse($"0.{i}", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); Console.WriteLine(dm); }`. The trailing zeros should be maintained, so `0.1` and `0.10` and `0.100` should print differently.

Answer (score 1):

```
    for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("0.{0}",i);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Answering strictly to your question without other assumptions. Just to print the numbers:

```
for(int i=1;i<=100;i++)
    {
       Console.WriteLine("0."+ (i<10 ? i+"0": i.ToString()));
    }
}
```

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama - He is complaining "value getting change from 0.10 to 1.0" so he wanted it i+"0". This is what I understand...

Comment: You are over-complicating it. It's just `Console.WriteLine("0." + i);`.

Comment: @DA OP wants 0.1, 0.2, etc. through to 0.100. Your code starts from 0.10 not 0.1.